# How to get script type,owner anme and object name from the string provided?

Tags: c#, regex

I can have

```sql
PROCEDURE dbo._ws_CallLogs_DeleteAll
```

OR

```sql
TABLE [dbo].[CachedPlan]
```

OR

```sql
VIEW [test].[MyView]
```

OR

```sql
FUNCTION [xyz].[ParseStringList]
```

as input

The output should be

**For Case 1**

```
string Type =  PROCEDURE
string DBOName = dbo
string obejctName = _ws_CallLogs_DeleteAll
```

**For Case 2**

```
string Type =  TABLE
string DBOName = dbo
string obejctName = CachedPlan
```

**For Case 3**

```
string Type = VIEW
string DBOName = test
string obejctName = MyView
```

**For Case 4**

```
string Type =  FUNCTION
string DBOName = xyz
string obejctName = ParseStringList
```

How to do so?

Comment: Do you want us to code it for you? What have you tried? Would you be better off using an SQL parsing libra ... wait, why are you parsing SQL? And can't you have `PROCEDURE fooProc`, `TABLE [dbo].[otherSchema].[Tablename]`, and `VIEW VIEW`? 
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex provided the input is in same form..

```
(?<type>PROCEDURE|TABLE|VIEW|FUNCTION)\s+\[?(?<name>\w+)\]?[.]\[?(?<object>\w+)\]?
```

Now you can get the match like this

```
Match m=Regex.Match(input,regex,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
m.Groups["type"].Value;//type
m.Groups["name"].Value;//name
m.Groups["object"].Value;//object
```

Comment: I tried  with input as var input = "PROCEDURE dbo._ws_CallLogs_DeleteAll"; but it is coming as blank

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar try it now..i guess you had used `@` before the string due to which \ got escaped instead of `[`,`]`

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar ohh..my bad i forgot to add `[]` for objectname...check out the edit..

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way of parsing it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var parser = new TSql100Parser(true);
    IList<ParseError> errors = new List<ParseError>();
    using (TextReader r = new StreamReader("sql.txt"))
    {
        var result = parser.GetTokenStream(r, errors);
        var results = result
            .Select((i, index) => (i.TokenType == TSqlTokenType.Create) ? index : -1)
            .Where(i => i >= 0)
            .Select(i => result.Skip(i + 1).TakeWhile(j =>
                (j.TokenType == TSqlTokenType.WhiteSpace
                || j.TokenType == TSqlTokenType.QuotedIdentifier
                || j.TokenType == TSqlTokenType.Identifier
                || j.TokenType == TSqlTokenType.Dot
                || j.TokenType == TSqlTokenType.Table
                || j.TokenType == TSqlTokenType.Procedure
                || j.TokenType == TSqlTokenType.View
                || j.TokenType == TSqlTokenType.Function
                ))
                .Where(j => (j.TokenType != TSqlTokenType.WhiteSpace 
                    && j.TokenType != TSqlTokenType.Dot))
                );

        foreach (var item in results)
        {
            var type = item.Where(i => (i.TokenType != TSqlTokenType.QuotedIdentifier
                || i.TokenType != TSqlTokenType.Identifier));
            Console.WriteLine("Type: {0}\tDbo: {1}\tObject: {2}",
                type.First().Text,
                type.Skip(1)
                    .Take(type.Count() - 2)
                    .Aggregate<TSqlParserToken, string>("", 
                        (a, b) => a + ((a == "") ? "" : ".") + b.Text),
                type.Last().Text);
        }
    }
}
```

You'll need the required references to the following namespaces:

```
using Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom.Sql;
using Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom;
```